# Powershell Invoke-Command with Variable for Script Name

Tags: powershell

I need to execute a Powershell script on a remote machine from a local script. Problem is, I don't know the path or filename of the remote script until runitime.

I've tried the following line in my local script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -ScriptBlock { & ($TargetMSI) '$MSI' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vasanta.Int.MIS' 'Dev' }
```

Problem is this returns the error: *The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an invalid object.*

If replace the $TargetMSI with a hard-coded string literal then it works fine.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you Invoke-Command in v2 there is no direct way to pass variables to scriptblock. You need to use -ArgumentList + param () in scriptblock combo:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param ($TargetMSI, $MSI) & $TargetMSI '$MSI' } -ArgumentList $TargetMSI, $MSI
```

this is fixed/ improved in v3 with $using:localvariable syntax.

Comment: Great, thanks Batek. My working line of code now looks as follows: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -ScriptBlock {param ($TargetMSI, $MSI, $InstallPath, $Environment) & $TargetMSI $MSI $InstallPath $Environment} -ArgumentList $TargetMSI, $MSI, $InstallPath, $Environment