# Restart-WebAppPool fails using foreach

Tags: powershell

I'm putting together a Powershell script that will recycle all currently running AppPools at a scheduled time early in the morning. For now I'm just trying to get it to work on a local machine and am getting an error "Cannot validate argument on Parameter 'Name'. The argument is null."

```
# Load IIS module:
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Get pool names:
$poolList = (Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -eq 
"Started"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name)

# Recycle Web App Pools
foreach ($item in $poolList)
{
Write-Host "Processing" $item -ForegroundColor Green
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {Restart-WebAppPool -
Name $item}
}
```

When I run the script it cycles through each AppPool item. I see that with this line...

```
Write-Host "Processing" $item -ForegroundColor Green
```

...but the Invoke-Command says the parameter 'Name' is null. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but don't know what it is.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Invoke-Command with Variable for Script Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738227/powershell-invoke-command-with-variable-for-script-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this issue because the variable $item is set out of scope. (Not sure if that's the best explanation.) You need to pass in an argument to the script block in Invoke-Command to be able to use it.

`Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $item {Restart-WebAppPool -Name $args[0]}`

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters into Invoke-Command script blocks isn't quite that simple, [but it is still pretty simple...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/29/how-to-pass-arguments-for-remote-commands/)

You'll want to check out the "Passing Local Values" section.

Comment: This also worked. Thank you for passing along the link for more info.