# Set-VMDvdDrive does not set my ISO media

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a task to mount my daily build image to a list of VMs by using powershell script `Set-VMDvdDrive`.

The problem is if I write the following code the image file will be mounted:

```
    Invoke-Command –ComputerName HyperVHostName -Credential Get-Credential –ScriptBlock{Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName myVM -Path G:\build.ISO}
```

But if I use a variable then the image file will not be mounted and the code does not throw any expceptions like this:

```
    $isoFile = "G:\build.ISO"
    Invoke-Command –ComputerName HyperVHostName -Credential Get-Credential –ScriptBlock{Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName myVM -Path $isoFile}
```

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Your scriptblock runs on another computer, it can't get a value for `$isoFile` which is a variable on your local computer? You need either -ArgumentList or 'using' - Possible duplicate of [Powershell Invoke-Command with Variable for Script Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738227/powershell-invoke-command-with-variable-for-script-name)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you very much :)